# How to fix Invalid Group By error in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm unable to resolve the error in the following code. It states invalid use of group by function. Please provide assistance where and how the group by function must be used here.

```
 select sh.current_sc_id as csid
      , extract(day from scdo.added_on) as 'Day'
      , sum(Case when 
               ( select count(date(scde.added_on)) 
                   from service_centre_doshipment scdo 
                   join service_centre_deliveryoutscan scde 
                     on scde.id = scdo.deliveryoutscan_id 
                  where sh.id = scdo.shipment_id 
                    and scde.origin_id = sh.service_centre_id ) = 1 
                 then sum(case when scdo.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) else 0 end) as 'Fresh_Delivered' /*used to calculate the count of on delieverd products*/
from service_centre_shipment sh 

 inner join service_centre_doshipment scdo 
      on sh.id = scdo.shipment_id 
   group 
      by csid;
```

Error Code:1111 Invalid use of group by function is the error message. I want to list down the centers and count the no of 'on time deliveries' that were made in the month of Oct across each day i.e Day 1 to Day 31.

There are basically 3 tables here - service_center_shipment (which has the details of all the shipments that were recieved in the service_center for processing.
service_center_doshipment - This contains the shipment that must be delievered in the given day at the service center.
service_center_deliveryoutscan - this entails the details about the shipment i.e whether it was delievered on time or if not.

Comment: Subqueries are not allowed as `GROUP BY` arguments.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Please publish the full error message, the version of mysql you are on and what only_full_group_by is set ti,

Comment: Error Code:1111 Invalid use of group by function is the error message. I want to list down the centers and count the no of 'on time deliveries' that were made in the month of Oct across each day i.e Day 1 to Day 31.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `Sum(Sum())` which is possible in output is allowed newer and nowhere.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: "sum(case when scdo.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end)" seems to be ambiguous can you remove sum and simply use case output?